# How to test if a value exists?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am using mongodb to build an app which get the user's twitter timeline in a mongodb database, I want to check if the tweets I got from twitter has already existed in my database, so I use the mongodb.`find()` function.

The whole function is like this:

```
db.collection.find({'twitterIAlreadyStored.id_str': newTweet.id_str}
```

Then I want to write a logical code which is:

```
if(exist){
} else {

}
```

So I am wondering if there is any way to test if the result of find exists or not??

Comment: `db.collection.find({'twitterIAlreadyStored.id_str': newTweet.id_str}).length() !== 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.find` only works if you are using the `mongo shell`.
what you're after is [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) queries, since you tagged `mongoose` I shall assume you've set it up.

Assuming that your `model` name is `twitterIAlreadyStored`

and the `property` you are looking in `id_str`

the `value` you're trying to find is `newTweet.id_str`

this would be the format to follow:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.model('MODELNAME').findOne({'PROPERTY': 'VALUE'}, function(error, exist) {
  if(exist && !error){
    //do something
  } else {
    //IF YOU ARE USING EXPRESS.JS, YOU MUST USE RES.SEND() or RES.END() TO TERMINATE THE CONNECTION
    res.status(500).send({"message" : "Not Found"});
    return;
  }
};
```

[express.js](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) doc on res.send() and res.end()

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solve my question with some editings..

Comment: i just provide the model name like this as my model is in models dir: const users = require('../models/users.models');, but its not working, err: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn&#39;t been registered for model &quot;model&quot;.